# Separate words in a sentence

Tags: r

I have a character vector:

```
5563,KIAA0006 gene,D13631_s_at                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
5566,Fatty acids omega-hydroxylase (cytochrome P-450HKV),D13705_s_at 
.......
```

R reads each line as a single word. (in reality the words are 3 or 4 , separated by a comma)
I want to create an element that contains only the last word in each row. (ex.D13631_s_at)

I do not know where to start

Comment: Are you reading these in from a csv file? If so there are some easy ways to parse the text

Answer (score 3):

If the data in a file you can do:

```
spam = read.table("file.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
spam[,3]
```

to get only the third column. For your example this yields:

```
> spam[,3]
[1] D13631_s_at   D13705_s_at  
Levels: D13631_s_at   D13705_s_at
```

Comment: probably with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` ?

Comment: THANK YOU for the answer, but it does not work, and the last word change maybe the third or fourth.

Comment: What does not work, with what error? Please add all the relevant aspects of your problem to your question.

Comment: golub.gnames3<-as.data.frame(golub.gnames2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)> dim(golub.gnames3)
[1] 3051    1
>

Comment: I have a matrix:

                t1    t2     t3
class            0     1       0
aa,bb,c         1.54  1.32    1.3
aa,vv,c,d       ...  ....     ...
aa,bb,hh,dd,ee  ...  ...      ....

I want to create an element:
x that contains only the lasta word of rownames (from the second):
x= "c, d, ee"

Comment: >  X<-read.table("C:\\Users\\acer\\dataproject1.txt",header =FALSE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> dim(X)
[1] 3053    1
>  X<-read.table("C:\\Users\\acer\\dataproject1.txt",header =FALSE, sep=",")
> dim(X)
[1] 3053    1
> class(X)
[1] "data.frame"
>

Comment: maybe your data contains quotes at the beginning and end of each line?

Comment: @ElisaVenturi please expand your question above to include the relevant details.

Comment: is a matrix sample with labeles and data,

Comment: and I want forthe rownames aa,bb,cc , the las word:cc